# why my Python requests code got 403 but postman work

Tags: python, python-requests, postman, http-status-code-403

I am sending a request to https://game.binaryx.pro, I need to set proxy to see the website's content.

Now the problem is the postman work, but my code returns 403, I dont know why.

here is my code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://game.binaryx.pro'

http_proxy  = "http://127.0.0.1:1080"
https_proxy = "https://127.0.0.1:1080"

proxyDict = {
    "https" : https_proxy,
    "http"  : http_proxy

}

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36'
}

res = requests.get(url, proxies=proxyDict)

print(res)
```

and I tried to use curl to access the website, but I got this:

[image]
[image]

Please help me fix this, thanks~!

Comment: Why did you bother to define `headers`, and then never use it?

Comment: Forbidden either means you're using the wrong url, or you're missing some headers that the site expects in order to gain access.

Comment: You need to use the user-agent you've defined.  That said, even if you do get the page's source, it's rendered with javascript, you won't find any of the text of the website on it.

Comment: aalways put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).

Comment: `postman` has function to generate Python code - maybe use it to see if you have all in your code.

Comment: @JohnGordon I have used the header, and try to copied the browers request's header in my code, but not work.

Comment: @furas I tried, didnt work

Comment: @AnonCoward thanks your message, I have tried put the successful request header(I copy it from browser), but still didnt  work.

Comment: this page uses service `CloudFlare` to detect scripts/bots/spamers/hackers - and it can check many other elements - like `cookies`, `JavaScript`, etc. `Curl` and `requests` can't run JavaScript. And may not use cookies. Your `curl` also gives `403` . `Postman` is created using engine `Electron` and language `JavaScript` so maybe `CloudFlare` detected that it can use JavaScript and it treats it as normal browser. You should read `res.text` to seee if there is more information. But frankly `CloudFlare` is good protection and normal methods may not work.

Comment: BTW: when I run url in `Postman` (but without proxy) then I don' t get 403 but still I get HTML with `We're sorry but BinaryX doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled`

Comment: @furas yes, like you said, I was blocked by CloudFlare, I mean when I use browser to access the website, I can see this service, too. But  I click a box to verify that I am a human being, so it redirect to the website. But in the code, how can I avoid the service or do something else?

Comment: @furas since postman can work, can I use python to call postma? Is there a way?

Comment: are you sure it works with Postman? As I said before: I tried use postman and it sends status 200 but it doesn't send HTML with page but only with warning `We're sorry but BinaryX doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled`. Status `200` doesn't mean that it sends `HTML` with expected values.

Comment: I don't know if there is special module to control `Postman` - like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser - but you may try to use module `PyAutoGUI` which can control `mouse` and `keyboard` and you can use this to control other programs. But frankly, I would rather use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser - it should run better.